# Does kubernetes Deployment automatically create the service like openshift DeploymentConfig does?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-3

I created a deployment using kubernetes Deployment in openshift cluster. i expected it to create the service for all the container ports like openshift DeploymentConfig does.
but i did not find any service created by the kubernetes Deployment.

does kubernetes Deployment not create the service automatically like openshift DeploymentConfig does ?

My openshift version is 3.11

Comment: No, we need to create Kubernetes service separately

Comment: could you please point to a doc that say openshift DeploymentConfig  create the service for all the container ports or if you could elaborate what is it that you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **Deployment** and **DeploymentConfig** does not create the **Service** component in OpenShift. These component are used for creation of Replication Control of the Pod.

Service has to be configured separately with the **selector** parameter to point to the specific Pods.

selector:
name: as in the deployment or in deploymentConfig.

This link would help you on the same.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Deployment and service are different kubernetes objects. Deployment doesnt automatically create service object. you need to define service definition in a YAML targeting the ports from the pod definition inside deployment manifests. You need to deploy both deployment and service objects. you can deploy then separately or bundle them together in a single YAML and deploy.

Further details follow the link --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/